React Native FlatList pagination
I want to implement pagination to my Chat, so when the user scrolls up, more messages are loaded. Currently I'm facing a problem that when I scroll up, more messages load, but the 'view' snaps to the top of the FlatList, and it just loads more because it thinks that the user scrolled there. I haven't been able to make the view stay put when loading new messages.
Initially 15 messages are loaded and when scrolling up, 15 more are loaded and added to the chat.
Code:


const Chat = ({ route }) => {

  const { user } = useContext(UserContext)

  const navigation = useNavigation()

  const { conversationId, friend: initialFriend } = route.params

  const flatListRef = useRef(null)

  const [isAtBottom, setIsAtBottom] = useState(true)

  const [isLoadingMore, setIsLoadingMore] = useState(false)

  const {

    friend, conversation, newMessage,

    setNewMessage, inputHeight, setInputHeight,

    loading, sendMessage, loadMoreMessages

  } = useChat(user, conversationId, initialFriend)



  const handleLoadMoreMessages = () => {

    if (loading || isAtBottom || isLoadingMore) return

    setIsLoadingMore(true)

    setTimeout(() => {

      loadMoreMessages()

      setIsLoadingMore(false)

    }, 300)

  }



  if (loading) {

    return (

      <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>

        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />

      </View>

    )

  }



  return (

    <ImageBackground source={defaultBackgroundPicture} style={styles.container}>

      <CustomNavBar navigation={navigation} friend={friend}/>

      <View style={styles.content}>

        <View style={styles.header}>

        </View>

        {conversation && <FlatList

          ref={flatListRef}

          key={conversationId}

          data={conversation.messages}

          keyExtractor={item => item && item._id ? item._id : uuid.v4()}

          renderItem={({ item }) => <MessageItem item={item} user={user} />}

          onScroll={({ nativeEvent }) => {

            const isCloseToBottom = nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height + nativeEvent.contentOffset.y >= nativeEvent.contentSize.height - 50

            setIsAtBottom(isCloseToBottom)

            if (nativeEvent.contentOffset.y < 20) {

              handleLoadMoreMessages()

            }

          }}

          onContentSizeChange={() => {

            if (isAtBottom) flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: false })

          }}

        />}

        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>

          <TextInput

            style={[styles.input, { height: Math.max(35, inputHeight) }]}

            value={newMessage}

            onChangeText={text => setNewMessage(text)}

            placeholder="Type a message..."

            multiline

            onContentSizeChange={(event) => {

              setInputHeight(event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height)

            }}

          />

          <Pressable style={styles.sendButton} onPress={() => {

            if (newMessage.length !== 0) sendMessage()

          }}>

            <Icon name="send" size={24} color="white" />

          </Pressable>

        </View>

      </View>

    </ImageBackground>



  )

}



I have been trying to play around with the onScroll and onContentSizeChange props of the flatlist.

I figured it out by switching my data fetching logic to use react-query and using inverted and onEndReached props in FlatList.
        <FlatList
      inverted
      ref={flatListRef}
      data={messagesData.pages.flatMap(page => {
        return page.conversation.messages
      })}
      keyExtractor={item => item && item._id ? item._id : uuid.v4()}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <MessageItem item={item} user={user} />}
      onEndReached={handleEndReached}
      onEndReachedTreshold={0.5}
    />

